# Ubuntu initialize in initramfs after i updated grub and reboot to try to solute notebook touchpad that wasn't working

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, initramfs, ideapad

i have a notebook lenovo ideapad s145 15iil, it came with windows 10, and everything was working perfectly, but i wanted use ubuntu, and when i installed ubuntu the problem appeard: the touchpad stopped to work and nothing that i did worked out, so i tried to edit grub using "sudo nano /etc/default/grub" and changing line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs quiet splash",then i used "sudo update-grub" and made reboot, thats when appeard this screen in the image, anyone know what is this and how can i resolve it? i just wanna use my notebook touchscreen and maybe some other keys that i cant use, like mic key for example

[thats the screen that appeared after all i said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVoMz.jpg)

Comment: It's a kernel bug. Check here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970056. Apparently, the boot drive is not recognized anymore using pci=nocrs in ubuntu 22.04 with kernel v5.15.

Comment: Did you find any fix?